# Thread Safe Compile Time Array

Tags: c++, thread-safety, compile-time, stdarray

I need to *operate* on a `std::array` by accessing/changing the array at given index as well as iterating over the elements of the array.

**Assuming the array elements are shared_ptr to thread safe objects**. Is there any concerns on the thread safety when *operating* on the array from different threads?

**Context**: How to make the below thread safe,

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>

struct SafeQueue
{
    void push(const double d) {};
    bool try_pop(double& d) {};
};

struct Broadcaster
{
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<SafeQueue>, 10> m_queues;
    void broadcast(const double d)
    {
        for(auto p : m_queues)
            if(p) p->push(d);
    }

    bool addQueue(const std::shared_ptr<SafeQueue>& q)
    {
        for(auto& p : m_queues)
            if(!p) 
            {
                p = q;
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Assume we are calling `broadcast` and `addQueue` from different threads.

I think I can solve this with atomic index but was thinking if there is any better.

Comment: If we assume the elements of the array are thread safe, then by definition isn't it thread safe to operate on the array? Or are your thread safety measures only on a per-element basis on not on the array as a whole?

Comment: @AndyG By thread safety I refer to the whole array. I was thinking no concerns as well just confirming as the std does not guarantee this (e.g. could the array be copied somewhere else by the OS, I don't think so) :) Thank you!

Comment: it's hard to say anything for sure without a code sample. For example, if individual elements are thread safe (e.g., each is an `atomic<T>`), then operating on those elements individually might be safe, but if you were to e.g., sum up the elements in the array, it's possible that by the time the operation completes, a value has changed and the sum is incorrect. (Whether that's a problem is another question)

Comment: I have added an example that is not thread safe and which is my case. In this case it's worse as the shared_ptr is not thread safe I think. Not really sure how to make the code thread safe but it certainly is not.

Comment: Thing is, nothing changes the array, so if the queues in the array are thread safe, you've already won. Unless you need to protect transactions, that is.

Comment: I still think the above code is wrong, imagine between the time I check if the pointer is non null and pushing a value, someone else changes the pointer and hence I will override (worse, in non-thread safe way) the pointer

Comment: Ahhh hahahah! Someone else can delete and add queues on the fly. Yes. Now you have a problem. Side note: `shared_ptr` may not be the right choice. Remember that it has a lot of extra overhead to support the sharing. There are aren't multiple legitimate owners, you're better off with a `unique_ptr`. Bot smart pointers will have the same failure cases here, so go with the cheaper option. Plus if you use `shared_ptr` and don't actually share it, readers of your code will draw the wrong conclusions about how to use the queues and probably insert bugs.

Comment: It is used just not in the example :)

Comment: All shared pointer protects WRT threading is the control block tracking the lifetime management stuff (the reference count) You can still horribly <expletive deleted> up the object it points at and get into ugliness with the validity of the pointer.

Comment: Multiple threads can simultaneously read and write different shared_ptr objects, even when the objects are copies that share ownership.

Comment: I still will override the pointer though?

Comment: But they cannot safely interact with the same `shared_ptr`, and that's what the asker seems worried about here.

Comment: @user4581301 They said in the comment above that by thread safety they mean whole array -- `std::array` is not thread-safe without using locks or some other concurrency containers or lock-free containers such as queues I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: In the given example, no one changes the `array` and no one accesses more than one item in the array at a time. They may change the contents of one `shared_ptr` at a time, and potentially do this while that `shared_ptr` is being copied. The question comes down to "Is copying a `shared_ptr` thread safe?"